# Using Polyfit to create 3rd degree polynomial with dynamic CSV's

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, plot

What the data look like although I may end up with more than just three columns:

```
TotalArea,Pressure,Intensity
12054.2,-0.067,39.579
11980.2,-0.061,41.011
11948,-0.055,42.08
11889.5,-0.04,45.732
11863.6,-0.03,50.573
```

My goal: I would like to take this `CSV` file and create A polynomial that will fit the column labeled `Intensity` and `TotalArea`.

My code (omitting anything I believe to be purely decorative):

```
Graph = pd.read_csv("C:Data.csv")

Pl = Graph.dropna()

Bottom = Pl["TotalArea"]
Right = Pl["Intensity"]
arr = Pl.values    


x = Bottom

y2 = Right
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xx = arr[:, [0]]
b = xx.ravel()
print(b)
yy = arr[:, [2]]
c = xx.ravel()



y3 = np.polyfit(b, c, 3)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y2, color = "r", label='Intensity /Area')  


plt.show()
```

My error: (has to do with polyfit values)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/WinPartition/Users/tomchi/Documents/Programming/Eclipse/PythonDevFiles/so_test.py", line 47, in <module>
    ax2.plot(x, y3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1855, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1527, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 406, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(this, kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 383, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 242, in _xy_from_xy
    "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (310,) and (2,)
```

So, my question is: What exactly does this mean? Is it due to pandas dataframe? Can I solve this in a quick manner? Can I be of any more assistance?

I realise now that polyfit just gives me the coefficients to my polynomial

```
[ -2.27230868e-23   2.74362531e-19   1.00000000e+00  -1.90568829e-12]
```

Comment: I could not Figure out how I could go about formatting it, I see you have helped me though! I appreciate it a bunch!

Comment: As for the error message: y3 stores the parameter of your linear fit function, not the actual y-values. You can easily create them with [np.polyval](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html)

Comment: You're the absolute best! I really am just the biggest noob when it comes to computers so your understanding and help is more than appreciated, I finally printed y3 and realized its just the coefficients!

Comment: No, I am not. I did exactly, what you did, just faster because of a little bit more experience. I hope this solves your problem. If you can rectify your code, [you are encouraged to post an answer to your own question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Please do not change the question, though or ask multiple questions -  please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And I gave you the hint that you should use np.polyval to get the y-values for your x-values.